# highlight a search word in LWC for each loop

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, css

I have the below code where i want to highlight a given word .But the word is not getting highlighted. Tried using  tag Below is the code. FOr this below given code, i am trying to highlight word "Check"

HTML

```
<template>

    <template for:each={recs} for:item="rec">
        <div key={rec.Title} class="slds-card"> {rec.Title}</div>
    </template>

</template>
```

JS

import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

```
export default class App extends LightningElement {
  recs = []
  

  connectedCallback(){
    this.recs = [{"CreatedByName":"David Guetta","CreatedDate":"6/10/2022","Id":"11111111111","showHideBy":"slds-hide","showHideclosureReason":"slds-show","Reason":"test","Status":"Subject Matter Expert Review","Title":"Check Highlight"},{"CreatedByName":"test","CreatedDate":"5/1/2022","Id":"222222222","showHideBy":"slds-hide","showHideclosureReason":"slds-show","Reason":"slds-hide","Status":"Subject Matter Expert Review","Title":"Check Highlight Check"}]
   this.recs.forEach(element => {
            if(element.Title){
                alert(element.Title)
                element.Title.replace(new RegExp('Check', 'ig'),(value)=>`<mark>${value}</mark>`);
            }
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to assign the returned value from replace function, taken from [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace): *The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement* so try this:

```
element.Title = element.Title.replace(new RegExp('Check', 'ig'),(value)=>`<mark>${value}</mark>`);
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: you might need to use this tag on your template:

```
<lightning-formatted-rich-text value={rec.Title}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a quick algorithm to break the parts up:

```
element.highlights = element.Title.replaceAll(RegExp(`(${searchTerm})`, "ig"), "\0$1\0")
  .split("\0")
  .reduce(
    (p, v) => {
      if (p.normal == undefined) {
        p.normal = v;
      } else {
        p.values.push({ key: p.values.length, normal: p.normal, mark: v });
        p.normal = undefined;
      }
      return p;
    },
    { values: [] }
  );
```

Which you can then display in your template:

```
<template for:each={recs} for:item="rec">
  <div key={rec.Title} class="slds-card">
    <template for:each={rec.highlights} for:each="highlight" >
      <span key={highlight.index} class="normal">{highlight.normal}</span>
      <mark key={highlight.index} class="bold">{highlight.mark}</mark>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

This has the advantage of not dealing with HTML directly in your JavaScript, at the cost of more markup.